# Keyboard Layout Indicator get disappeared after second login (login after logout)

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I`ve added two keyboard layouts because I use English as my second language.

Whenever I Logout (ubuntu 12.04 32bit) then Login, Keyboard layout disappears and it's not possible to switch between languages I've added before.

I tested that on my brother's laptop (ubuntu 12.04 64bit) and everything was ok.

Does anybody know what to do to get rid of this bad issue?

Comment: now i use 12.10 but still have the same problem that i explained. dos anybody know how to fix the annoying problem